# React - avoid dropdown to close when you develop the accordion inside the dropdown

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, accordion, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic UI React, my code structure looks like this:

```
 <Dropdown icon='plus'>
      <Dropdown.Menu >
             <Accordion>
              <Accordion.Title>
                   Test
              </Accordion.Title>
              <Accordion.Content>
                  Something
              </Accordion.Content>
            </Accordion>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
 </Dropdown>
```

I would like the accordion to not close the dropdown by clicking on its title. I tried using e.stopPropagation() on dropdown but it didn't work. Do you have any suggestions? :D

Comment: try using  `multiple`  `<Dropdown icon='plus' multiple >`

Comment: @PankajDivgi I've already tried, and still the same effect

Answer (score 0):

https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion

click on the first CodeSandBox button then click tick to open

on line 10 change:

```
const newIndex = activeIndex === index ? -1 : index
```

to:

```
 const newIndex = index;
```

save the change and test if for yourself.

you can tidy the function further:

```
  handleClick = (e, titleProps) => {
    const { index } = titleProps;
    this.setState({ activeIndex: index });
  };
```